# Spring JWT, missing information about role in database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jwt

Architecture: Spring Boot, Spring JWT, Hibernate, MySQL

Current situation:
Properly generated jwt token during sign up user. Also I have no problem with login.

Problem:
I have problem with user roles. Properly was sent etc., but does not save to database.

I have user table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    @Column(name="role")
    List<Role> roles;

    public User(){}

    public User(String login, String password, String email, List<Role> roles) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

   //getters and setters, toString();

}
```

Role enum:

```
public enum Role  implements GrantedAuthority {
    ROLE_ADMIN,
    ROLE_USER

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return name();
    }
}
```

But where I use findByLogin User, there is no information about Role. But another information exist.

```
@Override
    public User findByLogin(String loginUser) {

        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query findLoginQuery = currentSession
                .createQuery("from User where login=:login")
                .setParameter("login", loginUser);
        return (User) findLoginQuery.uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Check by adding Cascade Type ALL.

Comment: But I can only add cascade information in relation type, f.e. oneToMany etc.

Comment: Untested, therefore as comment: did you try adding `@Enumerated` since it's an enum?

Comment: Yes, before was only   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING). And that same result :(